# localStorage resets in IE11 after closing browser

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a web application deployed on Tomcat that uses `localStorage` (using the standard setItem, getItem functions). This works correctly for all browsers except IE11. For some reason in IE11 the `localStorage` resets itself after closing the browser; in IE10 with the same settings everything works ok.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: What have you looked at / tried? Any console errors? Does this happen in multiple instances of IE11 or just one machine? What settings do you have for the site or for IE itself (e.g. yyou can configure it to remove all web data on exit). Is the app definitely storing data during a session?

Comment: There are no console errors. I have tried from two remote machines to access the same instance of the application. In the first one, Firefox,Chrome and IE10 maintain localStorage as expected. In the second machine Firefox does so, but IE11 does not. I also found that other session data are missed as well, so maybe this is a configuration issue of IE. I checked the options of IE11, the only suspicious thing I found is that the option "Delete browsing history on exit" is checked. Could this be the problem?

Comment: I just tried unchecking this option and it works ok, so I guess this was the problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you disable Protected Mode in Security tab, IE don't reset localStorage and cookie.
[image: disable Protected Mode]